# Cómo puedo ajustar el tamaño de mi plantilla sin que se me desborden los elementos en ella?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Django, e importe una plantilla de boostrap llamada stisla. En el desarrollo del proyecto los componentes de la plantilla como la barra superior y los elementos que están contenidos en ella así como los elementos de los formularios y del restos de las vistas se me desfasaron de lugar. Alguien sabe como puedo corregir esto?

Comment: Hola Javier, por favor se un poco mas detallista en tu publicación, ¿que versión de bootstrap usas? ¿Puedes incluir alguna imagen?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.